# How to call a different function, depending on a value inside a v-on callback

Tags: vue.js

My code is

```
<form @submit.prevent="buttonName === 'Create' ? createCountries : updateCountries"> 
-----
----
</form>


methods :{
        createCountries(){
           ----
        },
        updateCountries(){
            -----
        }
}
```

its not working
i need to submit two method using condition in @submit.

How can i solve this. ??

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid doing logic like that in the template. Instead, bind a method to the submit event and within the method itself perform the necessary if/else method invocation:

```
<form @submit.prevent="onFormSubmit">
```

Then, in your methods:

```
onFormSubmit: function() {
    if (this.buttonName === 'Create')
        this.createCountries();
    else
        this.updateCountries();
}
```